# Did a group of Algerians celebrate the earthquake in Morocco near the border?

Tags: morocco

In an Iranian [website](https://www.tabnak.ir/fa/news/1192219/%D8%B4%D8%A7%D8%AF%DB%8C-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D8%B2%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B1%DB%8C%E2%80%8C%D9%87%D8%A7-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D9%88%D8%A7%DA%A9%D9%86%D8%B4-%D8%A8%D9%87-%D8%B2%D9%84%D8%B2%D9%84%D9%87-%D9%85%D8%B1%D8%A7%DA%A9%D8%B4) (and some other Iranian websites as well) they say a group of Algerians gathered at the border with Morocco and played music and celebrated the earthquake in Morocco (the two countries were somehow hostile to each other in history). There's also a videoclip in the website showing it (of course, it has a short advertisement in the beginning). It is said in the website that the videoclip is filmed by a Moroccan from the Morocco side. However, he is speaking in Arabic and I can't understand it.

> پس از وقوع زلزله 6.9 ریشتری در مراکش که به کشته شدن بیش از 1000 مراکشی منجر شد، دولت الجزایر برای ارسال کمک اعلام آمادگی کرد اما گروهی از مردم الجزایر در مرز مراکش به شادی پرداختند؛ مسئله‌ای که به دشمنی‌های قدیمی میان دو کشور بازمی‌گردد. تصاویر این شادی با ساز و دهل که توسط یک مراکشی از آن سوی مرز ثبت شده را در تابناک می‌بینید.

It translates to: *After 6.9 earthquake in Morocco which resulted in the deaths of more than 1000 Moroccans, Algerian government announced they are ready to send help. But a group of Algerians celebrated the earthquake at the Moroccan border; which roots in the old hostilities between two countries. You see the video of this celebration that is filmed by a Moroccan near the border in Tabnak website*.

I tried to find a reliable source proving it in English language news agencies. But I only found these two TikTok videos (one of them is the exact video of the Iranian website).

[TikTok Search 1](https://www.tiktok.com/discover/Algerians-laughing-at-Morocco-earthquake) and [TikTok Search 2](https://www.tiktok.com/discover/Algerians-celebrating-morocco-earthquake)

Is there a famous site speaking about this? Is this celebration a real thing?

Comment: I heard about it on radio this morning. The journalist explained that the video of Algerians celebrating was more than one year old and obviously related to the recent earthcake.

Comment: @Evargalo: Did you mean "obviously **not** related"?

Comment: @Schmuddi : yes, obviously not related. I unfortunalety forgot one little important word, I hope complotists won't take advantage of this...

Comment: @Evargalo Not anymore

Comment: "*the two countries were somehow hostile to each other in history"*. They are [hostile now](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-africa-66704750).